# Create a dynamic XSL based on XML

Tags: xml, xslt

I am having my XML as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DeploymentReport xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02">
<Alerts><Alert Name="DataMotion"><Issue Value="Some value" /><Issue Value="Table" /></Alert><Alert Name="DataIssue"><Issue Value="Actual description" Id="1" /><Issue Value="Actual description." Id="2" /></Alert></Alerts>
<Operations>
<Operation Name="Create">
<Item Value="[dbo].[tblEmployee].[IX_tblEmployee]" Type="SqlIndex" />
<Item Value="[dbo].[TestProc]" Type="SqlProcedure" />
<Item Value="[dbo].[TestProc1]" Type="SqlProcedure" />
</Operation>
</Operations>
</DeploymentReport>
```

I need to generate a dynamic `XSL` file or an `XSL` file which will show all `Type` in one `html Table` can some one help me I tried some thing as below which didn't worked

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Table</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="Operation/Item/Value">
            <tr>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="Value"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="Value"/></td>
              <td><xsl:value-of select="Value"/></td>
            </tr>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result of XSL I am expecting is to display as below all Types under on `tr` `td`
[image]

Rough idea on html

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<html xmlns:bar="http://www.bar.org" xmlns:foo="http://www.foo.org/">
   <body>
      <table border="1">
         <tr>
         <th>SqlProcedure</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>TestProc</td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>TestProc1</td>
            </tr>
         <tr>
         <th>SqlIndex</th></tr>
         <tr>
            <td>IX_tblEmployee</td>

         </tr>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you please add the desired html output?

Comment: I need it some thing like as shown in the image all types under one `TR`

Comment: it would make it easier for those willing to help if you could share it as html source

Comment: `Stefan Hegny` updated my rough idea

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you first want to group by `@Type`, assuming you really need to use XSLT 1.0 then use [Muenchian grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:report="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02" exclude-result-prefixes="report">
  <xsl:key name="type" match="report:Item" use="@Type"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr bgcolor="#9acd32">
            <th>Table</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:for-each select="//report:Operation/report:Item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('type', @Type)[1])]">
            <tr>
              <td>
                  <xsl:value-of select="@Type"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('type', @Type)">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi small help I am having alerts as per edited question I tried as follows `<xsl:key name="value" match="report:Issue" use="@Value"/>` `<table style="border:1px solid;" align="center"><xsl:for-each select="//report:Issue/report:Item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('value', @Value)[1])]"><tr style="text-align:center;"><td style="color:red"><xsl:value-of select="@Value"/> </td></tr>
<xsl:for-each select="key('value', @Value)"><tr><td>                        <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/></td></tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>`

Comment: Can you help me

Comment: If you have a different input now and can't adapt the solution on your own then consider to ask a new question with all details like input XML, XSLT you have tried, output you want and output you get. It doesn't make much sense to edit a question two weeks after it was asked and to show some code in a comment, at least that makes it very hard to read the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43778905/create-a-dynamic-xsl-and-generate-html