# Create a dynamic XSL and generate html

Tags: xml, xslt

Need improvement for the same question here [Create a dynamic XSL based on XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43581267/create-a-dynamic-xsl-based-on-xml)

I am having my XML as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><DeploymentReport xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02">
<Alerts>
    <Alert Name="DataMotion">
        <Issue Value="[dbo].[table]" />
        <Issue Value="[dbo].[table1]" />
    </Alert>
    <Alert Name="DataIssue">
        <Issue Value="The column [table].[Columname] on table [dbo].[table] must be added, but the column has no default value and does not allow NULL values. If the table contains data, the ALTER script will not work. To avoid this issue you must either: add a default value to the column, mark it as allowing NULL values, or enable the generation of smart-defaults as a deployment option." Id="1" />
        <Issue Value="The column [table1].[Columname] on table [dbo].[table1] must be added, but the column has no default value and does not allow NULL values. If the table contains data, the ALTER script will not work. To avoid this issue you must either: add a default value to the column, mark it as allowing NULL values, or enable the generation of smart-defaults as a deployment option." Id="2" />
    </Alert>
</Alerts>
<Operations>
    <Operation Name="Drop">
        <Item Value="[dbo].[tbl].[IX_id]" Type="SqlIndex" />
    </Operation>
    <Operation Name="TableRebuild">
        <Item Value="[dbo].[tbl]" Type="SqlTable">
            <Issue Id="1" />
        </Item>
        <Item Value="[dbo].[tbl1]" Type="SqlTable">
            <Issue Id="2" />
        </Item>
    </Operation>
    <Operation Name="Create">

    </Operation>
</Operations>
</DeploymentReport>
```

XSL that was modified by previous answer

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:report="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02" exclude-result-prefixes="report">
  <xsl:key name="type" match="report:Item" use="@Type"/>
<xsl:key name="value" match="report:Issue" use="@Value"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
      <table style="border:1px solid;" align="center">
          <xsl:for-each select="//report:Issue/report:Item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('value', @Value)[1])]">
            <tr style="text-align:center;">
              <td style="color:red">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('value', @Value)">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        <table style="border:1px solid;" align="center">
          <xsl:for-each select="//report:Operation/report:Item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('type', @Type)[1])]">
            <tr style="text-align:center;">
              <td style="color:red">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@Type"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('type', @Type)">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected html should be as follows

```
<table style="border:1px solid;" align="center">
<tr>
<td style="color:red">
    DataIssue
</td>
<tr>
<td>
 1) The column [table].[Columname] on table [dbo].[table] must be added, but the column has no default value and does not allow NULL values. If the table contains data, the ALTER script will not work. To avoid this issue you must either: add a default value to the column, mark it as allowing NULL values, or enable the generation of smart-defaults as a deployment option
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
2) The column [table].[Columname] on table [dbo].[table] must be added, but the column has no default value and does not allow NULL values. If the table contains data, the ALTER script will not work. To avoid this issue you must either: add a default value to the column, mark it as allowing NULL values, or enable the generation of smart-defaults as a deployment option
</td>
</tr>
<td>
N  number) The column [table].[Columname] on table [dbo].[table] must be added, but the column has no default value and does not allow NULL values. If the table contains data, the ALTER script will not work. To avoid this issue you must either: add a default value to the column, mark it as allowing NULL values, or enable the generation of smart-defaults as a deployment option
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color:red">
    Drop - SqlIndex (combination of Operation name and Item type)
</td>
<tr>
<td>
 [dbo].[tbl].[IX_id]
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color:red">
    TableRebuild - SqlTable
</td>
<tr>
<td>
 1 ) [dbo].[tbl1]
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
 2 ) [dbo].[tbl2]
</td>
</tr>
<td style="color:red">
    Create - SqlIndex
</td>
<tr>
<td>
 1 ) [dbo].[index1]
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
 2 ) [dbo].[index2]
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Please state the exact nature of the problem. Where does the output not conform to your expectations?

Comment: I am not getting how to group Alerts as per the requirement posed in html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need grouping for your `Alert` issues. It looks like you simply want to output Alert issues which are referenced by "Item/Issue" records.

So, what you can do, is define a key like to look up "Item/Issue" records by id.

```
<xsl:key name="issue" match="report:Item/report:Issue" use="@Id"/>
```

Then, to get only `Alert` elements with referenced `Issue` elements, you can do this...

```
 <xsl:for-each select="//report:Alert[report:Issue[key('issue', @Id)]]">
```

And within this, you can get the issues like so

```
<xsl:for-each select="report:Issue[key('issue', @Id)]">
```

As for the listing of the `Operation` elements, it looks like you now want to group the issues by parent operation name, and by issue type, so you need a concatenated key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="type" match="report:Item" use="concat(../@Name, '|', @Type)"/>
```

You can then use it in the same way though. Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:report="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/dac/DeployReport/2012/02" 
                exclude-result-prefixes="report">

  <xsl:key name="type" match="report:Item" use="concat(../@Name, '|', @Type)"/>
  <xsl:key name="issue" match="report:Item/report:Issue" use="@Id"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
      <table style="border:1px solid;" align="center">
          <xsl:for-each select="//report:Alert[report:Issue[key('issue', @Id)]]">
            <tr style="text-align:center;">
              <td style="color:red">
                  <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="report:Issue[key('issue', @Id)]">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
        <table style="border:1px solid;" align="center">
          <xsl:for-each select="//report:Operation/report:Item[generate-id() = generate-id(key('type', concat(../@Name, '|', @Type))[1])]">
            <tr style="text-align:center;">
              <td style="color:red">
                  <xsl:value-of select="concat(../@Name, ' - ', @Type)"/>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <xsl:for-each select="key('type', concat(../@Name, '|', @Type))">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="@Value"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks `Tim C` can we concat our own messages along with value?

Comment: I am not entirely sure what you mean, but you can add as many parameters as you like to the `concat` statement, or have more `xsl:value-of` statements on separate lines, so it shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: I mean to say can we add custom text like the following  index has been dropped [dbo].[index2] concatenating with actual value

Comment: Yes, you can. You could possibly use an `xsl:choose` to set the text based on the `type` attribute. Or you could use `xsl:apply-templates` instead of `xsl:for-each` and have a separate template match for each type.